# How to prove $ (2n)! < {2}^{2n} (n!)^2 $

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, factorial

I am proving this statement.

$$ (2n)! <  {2}^{2n}  (n!)^2   $$

I proved it for $n=1$.

Did the induction hypothesis for $n+1$.

$(2n+2)! < 2^{2n+2}((n+1)!)^2 $

But I get stuck at this step,

$(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)! < 2^{n} * 2^2 (n+1)^2 (n!)^2 $

What should I do next?

Comment: Man, it must be the "factorials + inequalities + induction" chapter in some course recently. (At least it seems to me we've been getting lots of these types of questions recently)

Comment: You want to show that:$$(2n+2)(2n+1)<4(n+1)^2=(2n+2)(2n+2)$$Is this obvious enough for you?

Comment: $$\binom{2n}{n}< 4^n$$ is pretty well-known and not difficult to prove. Actually $$ \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\sin\theta\right)^{2n}\,d\theta \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt As mentioned in my answer, your comment deals with the main substance of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
2^{2n}=(1+1)^{2n}=\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\binom {2n}r\; &> \; \binom {2n}n=\frac {(2n)!}{n!n!}.\\
\therefore\ (2n)!\; &<\; 2^{2n}(n!)^2.\end{align}$$

Comment: My edit was only to add punctuation...+1

Comment: (+1) I hope you dont mind that I added the $\therefore$ sign.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet - Thanks for the edit and upvote!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - Thanks for the edit and upvote!

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\frac {(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\frac {2n\cdot2(n-1)\cdot2(n-2)\dots 2}{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot{n-2}\dots 1}\cdot\frac {2n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{2n-3}{n-1}\dots\cdot \frac 11$$

The first fraction is just $2^n$ (taking the even numbers from $(2n)!$) and each of the $n$ factors in the second part (odd numerators) is less than $2$

@SimplyBeautifulArt has answered your main question in a comment, so this is just an alternative way of looking at things.

Comment: Now I see how we get to $$ \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} <2^n $$

But  i still do not understand how it holds for $n ≥ 4$ 

$$ \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} <2^n $$



Could you rephrase why is the first fraction $2^n$ ?

$\frac {(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\frac {2n\cdot2(n-1)\cdot2(n-2)\dots 2}{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot{n-2}\dots 1}\cdot\frac {2n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{2n-3}{n-1}\dots\cdot \frac 11$

Comment: I am picking out the even factors of $(2n)!$ first because you can divide by $n!$ easily - these are $2n\cdot 2n-2\cdot 2n-4\dots\cdot 2$. There are $n$ even factors, each twice a factor of $n!$. For $n=3$ this is $6 \cdot  4\cdot 2$ which is $2^3 \cdot 3\cdot 2 \cdot 1$

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, you want $$2^{2n} > \binom{2n}{n}$$ which is combinatorially obvious: the $n$-sized subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ can't outnumber the total subsets of that set.